# Сравнить строки двух файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Я получил названия всех файлов с расширением `.php` из директорий, которые мне нужны, при помощи этого кода:

```
import os

os.chdir("/opt/lampp/htdocs/phpBB3")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown = False):
   for name in files:
    if name.endswith('.php'):
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
   for name in dirs:
    if name.endswith('.php'):
            print(os.path.join(root, name))
```

и записал их в файл, когда запускал скрипт:

```
$ python3 search.py > allfiles.txt
```

У меня есть ещё один `test.txt` с именами файлов, нужно в `allfiles.txt` оставить только те названия файлов, которые есть в `test.txt`

Как мне это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Предполагая, что у вас уже открыты файлы*

```
files_to_test = test.readlines()
all_files = allfiles.readlines()
intersection = list(set(files_to_test) & set(all_files))
```

После этого в списке `intersection` останутся только строки, встретившиеся в обоих файлах.

### Пояснение

`set` в Python представлят [множество](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) в математическом смысле. Одна из операций над множествами - [пересечение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2). Результатом этой операции является множество, содержащее элементы встречающиеся в обоих операндах. Соответсвенно, в python класс `set` реализует операцию "пересечение" через оператор `&`.

Comment: Так это уберет повторяющиеся строки из `all_files`

Comment: @dIm0n а там нет повторяющихся строк, потому что у автора в ``allfiles`` пишется полное имя файла.